# How can I send data from the desktop application to the database after the latter is closed without user intervention?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I'm developing a Java Swing desktop application that does the user's time tracking. I am currently sending the data to the database when I click on the closing cross or when I log out. But I would like to optimize this application by sending the data if, for example, the application closes following a system shutdown without user intervention. Can you please help me on this case?

This is an exemple for my implementation when I click in the close windows :

```
frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
        endBreak = formatterEndDate.format(new Date());
        endDate = new Date();
        stopProduction();
        coffebreaktime.setText(hoursCoffeBreakShow + ":" + minutesCoffeBreakShow + ":" + secondsCoffeBreakShow);
        lunchbreaktime.setText(hoursLunchShow + ":" + minutesLunchShow + ":" + 

        e.getWindow().dispose();

        try {
            try {
                sendDataToDataBase(); // function de send data to database when closing the application
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
           MyLogger.logger.info("Frame closed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That version is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). If you really use it, you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: No, i'm using the last version of Postgresql (11) but i have made a mistake in the tag !